# how to make custom error feedback messages in SignInPanel in Wicket

Tags: passwords, ldap, wicket, feedback

I am implementing a LoginPage with Wicket, and I am not getting it, how to write the custom Feedback messages, for ex, "Password is wrong", "Username is wrong" or "Accound is locked out"  (the last example should be a bit more difficult because it is related to Ldap/Ldap error messages I think.. But I think there is an easier way for the second two, with the properties file of my LoginPage or something like that.. I tried to change the default Wicket "login failed" message, and this through the properties' file of my page, I just added "signFailed=Sign in failed TEST", and it got changed.. but didn't got it how to tell the user why! Pass or username is wrong!

here the implementation:

```
public class LoginPage extends SampleManagementPage {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -8585718500226951823L;
private SignInPanel signIn;


public LoginPage() {
    signIn = new SignInPanel("signInPanel");
    add(signIn);
}

}
```

and my SampleManagementPage extends WebPage!

here the properties' file of LoginPage:

page.title=Login for Sample Management

signInFailed=Sign in failed TEST

Comment: SignInPanel may contain a bit more relevant code, can you add that code too?

Comment: SignInPanel is given by Wicket.. I didnt add any code.. thats all I have

Comment: anyone could answer??

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are able to change only the signFailed error message, is that wicket SignInPanel throws only this particular error in case it's sign-in form fails to authenticate. To see that, you can open the source code of `SignInPanel.java`.

One way to overcome the problem and produce your own error messages, is write your own sign-in panel. I m not saying it is the only way but it worked for me :)

```
public class LoginPanel extends Panel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1662154893824849377L;

    private static final String SIGN_IN_FORM = "signInForm";

    private boolean includeRememberMe = true;
    private boolean rememberMe = true;
    private String password;
    private String username;

    public LoginPanel(final String id, final boolean includeRememberMe) {
        super(id);
        this.includeRememberMe = includeRememberMe;
        add(new FeedbackPanel("feedback"));
        add(new SignInForm(SIGN_IN_FORM));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onConfigure() {
        if (isSignedIn() == false) {
            IAuthenticationStrategy authenticationStrategy = getApplication().getSecuritySettings().getAuthenticationStrategy();
            String[] data = authenticationStrategy.load();
            if ((data != null) && (data.length > 1)) {
                if (signIn(data[0], data[1])) {
                    username = data[0];
                    password = data[1];
                    onSignInRemembered();
                } else {
                    authenticationStrategy.remove();
                }
            }
        }
        super.onConfigure();
    }

    private boolean signIn(String username, String password) {
        return AuthenticatedWebSession.get().signIn(username, password);
    }

    private boolean userExists(String username) {
        return ((MyWebSession) AuthenticatedWebSession.get()).userExists(username);
    }

    private boolean isSignedIn() {
        return AuthenticatedWebSession.get().isSignedIn();
    }

    protected void onSignInFailed() {
        error(getLocalizer().getString("signInFailed", this, "Wrong password"));
    }

    private void onUserExistsFailed() {
        error(getLocalizer().getString("userExistsFailed", this, "User does not exist"));
    }

    protected void onSignInSucceeded() {
        continueToOriginalDestination();
        setResponsePage(getApplication().getHomePage());
    }

    protected void onSignInRemembered() {
        continueToOriginalDestination();
        throw new RestartResponseException(getApplication().getHomePage());
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public LoginPanel(final String id) {
        this(id, true);
    }

    public final class SignInForm extends StatelessForm<LoginPanel> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public SignInForm(final String id) {
            super(id);

            setModel(new CompoundPropertyModel<LoginPanel>(LoginPanel.this));

            add(new TextField<String>("username"));
        add(new PasswordTextField("password"));

            WebMarkupContainer rememberMeRow = new WebMarkupContainer("rememberMeRow");
            add(rememberMeRow);

            rememberMeRow.add(new CheckBox("rememberMe"));

            rememberMeRow.setVisible(includeRememberMe);
        }

        @Override
        public final void onSubmit() {
            IAuthenticationStrategy strategy = getApplication().getSecuritySettings().getAuthenticationStrategy();

            if (!userExists(username)) {
                onUserExistsFailed();
                strategy.remove();
                return;
            }

            if (signIn(getUsername(), getPassword())) {
                if (rememberMe == true) {
                    strategy.save(username, password);
                } else {
                    strategy.remove();
                }

                onSignInSucceeded();
            } else {
                onSignInFailed();
                strategy.remove();
            }
        }
    }

}



public class MyWebSession extends AuthenticatedWebSession {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -401924496527311251L;

    public MyWebSession(Request request) {
        super(request);
    }

    public boolean userExists(String username) {
        // business login
    }

    @Override
    public boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
        // business login
    }

    @Override
    public Roles getRoles() {
        Roles roles  = new Roles();
        roles.add(Roles.USER);
        return roles;
    }

}
```

Comment: `userExistsFailed` is a security issue; it gives information on usernames. Please make sure in your implementation the errormessage in both cases is something like 'Username and password do not match'

Comment: The observation is correct! Thanks for mentioning :)